# pid func doesn't work with pairwiseAlignment R

Tags: r

I wrote this code:

```
library(Biostrings)

setwd("C:/Users/User/Documents/SaturdayProject/mDNK/monkeys")

data <- list.files()

tab <- matrix(0, 33, 33, TRUE, NULL)

i <- 1
j <- 1

for (file in data){
  d1 <- paste( unlist(read.delim(file)), collapse='')
  for (file1 in data){
    d2 <- paste( unlist(read.delim(file1)), collapse='')
    ack1 <- pid(pairwiseAlignment(d1,d2, scoreOnly = TRUE), type = "PID1")
    ack2 <- pid(pairwiseAlignment(d2,d1, scoreOnly = TRUE), type = "PID1")
    ###print(mean(ack1,ack2))
    tab[i,j] <- mean(ack1, ack2)
    j <- j + 1
    print(tab)
  }
  j <- 1
  i <- i + 1
}

print("end")
```

However I got this:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘pid’ for signature ‘"numeric"’

without pid it's works well.

Comment: It seems the `pid()` function is not designed to handle the type of data you are passing through it.  Please add sample of data what you are trying to read

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Y2Kot/f94fa6fd954d3ba2da9fc6e5f70a9150

Comment: PID works with short seq like: "CAGGAAAGATTAAAAGAAGTAAAAGGAACTC" but doesn't work with my files when using pid (without pid it's works with my files)